# Download a file using http client from ftp server

Tags: c++, qt, http, ftp

I have an existing `C++/Qt` source code for the firmware update. *HTTP client* used to download the file.

This piece of code works fine if I'll provide `http://<path to file>`
But *http* client failed to download from `ftp://<path to down load>`. It shows downloaded file size zero with ftp.

As per StackOverflow, It should work for for both. I try to use `setScheme("ftp")` and other small changes. But does not work.

```
void HttpClient::onDownloadProgress(qint64 bytesReceived,
                                        qint64 bytesTotal)
{
    emit downloadUpdateProgress(
        static_cast<int>((bytesReceived * 1.0f / bytesTotal * 1.0f) * 100));
}

void HttpClient::onReadyRead()
{
    auto reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(QObject::sender());
    if (reply) {
        QNetworkRequest request(reply->request());
        auto device = qobject_cast<QIODevice *>(request.originatingObject());
        if (device) {
            device->write(reply->readAll());
        }
    }
}

bool HttpClient::post(const QUrl &url, const QByteArray &data,
                          QIODevice *device)
{

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
                      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute,
                         QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork);
    request.setSslConfiguration(getSslConfig());
    request.setOriginatingObject(device);

    QNetworkReply *reply = _networkAccessManager->post(request, data);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &HttpClientImpl::onReadyRead);

    bool result = waitForFinished(reply, 30 * 1000);
    return result;
}

bool HttpClientImpl::get(const QUrl &url, QIODevice *device) 
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setSslConfiguration(getSslConfig());
    request.setOriginatingObject(device);

    QNetworkReply *reply = _networkAccessManager->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::downloadProgress, this,
            &HttpClientImpl::onDownloadProgress);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &HttpClientImpl::onReadyRead);

    bool result = waitForFinished(reply);
    return result;
}
```

It should download the correct file size.

Comment: Why would you expect a HTTP client to be able to download stuff using the FTP protocol? They are *different* protocols.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the code is using [`QNetworkAccessManager`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), which supports multiple protocols, including HTTP and FTP, based on what type of URL it is given.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK, but then it does not act as an HTTP client, but as an FTP client, so the question is still misleading.

Comment: If the request URL is started from "http://" the function get() works as expected for HTTP protocol. If the URL is started by "ftp://", get() will download the required file using FTP protocol. QNetworkAccessManager provides these functions.

Comment: @ErikNielsen even though you don't get the file size reported, are you able to download the actual file OK via FTP?  It is a harder to get progress with FTP than HTTP. FTP does not report a file's size before transferring bytes. You can know the number of bytes actually transferred but not the total bytes expected. You have to query the file's size beforehand via a directory listing request. That is not the case with HTTP, as the file's size is *usually* reported up front when the transfer begins. I say *usually* because there are scenarios where that is not the case (live streaming, etc).